# How to differentiate modded servers in the server browser?

Tags: killing-floor

Are modded servers displayed in a different way? Some of the description text and map names vary in color, but given the wild variation I assume that can be modified by the host.
For instance, the first server in the list is using a custom map "KF-Doom2-Final-v7" and the text appearance seems to be identical with the default maps such as "KF-Manor" and "KF-Mountainpass".

Checking "perks enabled" search setting removes servers where perk experience can't be gained, but the developer Tripwire has an extensive whitelist for accepted [mods](http://kf-wiki.com/wiki/List_of_whitelisted_and_greylisted_mutators) ("mutators"). Since the [8th of November 2012 patch](http://kf-wiki.com/wiki/List_of_2012_updates#8th_November_2012) perk progression has been allowed on all maps ([source](http://kf-wiki.com/wiki/List_of_whitelisted_maps)) and hence all custom levels appear in the search.

[image: server browser]

*server browser* ([tooltips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9yyS.png) for icons on the left)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active mutators are listed in the server settings (a server has to be selected):

[image: server browser]